# Visual Studio C++ access violation when modifying a pointer passed into a function

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2012

I want to implement a simple function that gets a string as a char pointer and modifies the string in a function. The requested function must be void then I have  to modify the primary string passed into my function. I got an access violation error and googled it but nothing helped.

My sample code is here:

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
void FindCommonStr(char*& Common,int &A)
{   
    int i=0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(Common[i]=='\0')
            break;
        i++;
    }
    cout<<"Number of Elements = "<<i<<endl;
    for (int j=0 ; j<i-1;j++)   
        Common[j]='y';      
    A=2;    
}
void main()
{
    int A=0;    
    char* Common = new char;
    Common = "Hello World!";
    cout<<"Common0 = "<< Common<<endl;
    cout<<"A0 = "<< A<<endl;
    FindCommonStr(Common,A);    
    cout<<"Common1 = "<< Common<<endl;
    cout<<"A1 = "<< A<<endl;
}
```

Actually the problem occured in this part of `FindCommonStr` funtion:

```
for (int j=0 ; j<i-1;j++)   
            Common[j]='y';
```

If I comment this part everything works but I cannot change the string values. I also tested the pointer to pointer solution by defining the function as:

```
FindCommonStr(char **Common,...
```

It doesn't help though and I got the violation error again.
Is it even possible to do such a thing?

Comment: `char* Common = new char; Common = "Hello World!";` is like `int i = 5; i = 6;`.

Comment: @Biological System - new char allocates the memory for only one character. Try to avoid using new and prefer to use objects like Paul R does in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Common = "Hello World!";
```

you are making the pointer `Common` point at a literal C-style string (and incidentally leaking the original `char` that you allocated via `new` previously). It is not valid to try to modify such a literal, so when you pass this to `FindCommonStr` and try to modify it you get an access violation.

You should avoid using C-style strings and use proper C++ `std::string` instead - this will save a lot of problems and is much more robust, as well as being more appropriate for C++ programming.

Fixed version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static void FindCommonStr(string &Common, int &A)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (Common[i] == '\0')
            break;
        i++;
    }
    cout << "Number of Elements = " << i << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
        Common[j] = 'y';
    A = 2;
}

int main()
{
    int A = 0;
    string Common = "Hello World!";
    cout << "Common0 = " << Common << endl;
    cout << "A0 = " << A << endl;
    FindCommonStr(Common, A);
    cout << "Common1 = " << Common<<endl;
    cout << "A1 = " << A << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively if this is a homework assignment where you are required to use C strings for some unfathomable reason then a fixed version using only `char *` strings might look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static void FindCommonStr(char *Common, int &A)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (Common[i] == '\0')
            break;
        i++;
    }
    cout << "Number of Elements = " << i << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
        Common[j] = 'y';
    A = 2;
}

int main()
{
    int A = 0;
    char Common[] = "Hello World!";
    cout << "Common0 = " << Common << endl;
    cout << "A0 = " << A << endl;
    FindCommonStr(Common, A);
    cout << "Common1 = " << Common<<endl;
    cout << "A1 = " << A << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I got the problem I have about char* Common = new char; and
    Common = "Hello World!"; but the problem is I have to define the function with char it is requested. anyway just I found a good answer where if I define new pointer in the function and equal the Common to this new pointer everything will be solved.

Comment: OK - I have also added a fixed version to the answer now which uses C strings rather than C++ strings.

Comment: The alternate code you posted still has the problem. the function should be look like this: void FindCommonStr(char*& Common, int &A). and in the the function defining new string: char* temp; and then fill temp with anything we wanted like: temp="bla bla";  then just change the Common pointer to the temp as this: Common=temp;____ In this manner Common will change to "bla bla" outside of the function too. ____ Thanks

Comment: @BiologicalSystem: there is no need to make the `Common` parameter a reference. If you run the code I think you'll find it's correct - see: http://codepad.org/EQ7kW0gW. However your question isn't very clear, so perhaps you're trying do something different that you haven't explained in the question?

Comment: yes you are right. I got error because I declare Common with "new" but if it is declared as you said it will works fine.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This part is **conceptually** wrong:

```
char* Common = new char;
// 'Common' is set to point to a piece of allocated memory
// (typically located in the heap)

Common = "Hello World!";
// 'Common' is set to point to a constant string
// (typically located in the code-section or in the data-section)
```

You are assigning variable `Common` twice, so obviously, the first assignment has no meaning.

It's like writing:

```
int i = 5;
i = 6;
```

On top of that, you "lose" the address of the allocated memory block, so you will not be able to release it at a later point in the execution of your program.

Comment: True, but this isn't the cause of the Access Violation.

Comment: @MSalters: True, but I saw it necessary to point out to OP the conceptual misunderstanding, by showing it in an equivalent (and simpler) example. The purpose wasn't to provide a full-coverage answer (since one had already been given by the time I wrote it), but to emphasize this fundamental issue.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mixup char[] and string

When you write

```
char* Common = new char;
```

you allocate space on the heap for one character which `Common` is pointing to.

Then you write

```
Common = "Hello World!";
```

which sets the pointer Common to point to the string "Hello World" in read-only memory. The heap you allocated previously is now leaked.

There are basically two approaches:

Either you work with arrays of characters, in that case you write something like

```
char* Common = new char[strlen("Hello World!")+1];
strcpy(Common, "Hello World!");
```

Now common still points to the heap and the string has been copied there. The extra +1 byte is to hold the ending \0 string terminator.

You need to free the memory Common points to once you are done.

```
delete Common;
```

The other approach is to use the string template

```
std::string Common;
```

this allows you to assign a string, it capsules all the work with the heap array above.

```
Common = "Hello World!";
```

and there is no need to delete anything afterwards since std::string will do that for you.